# A combined promise is resolved before any sub-promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am using AngularJS and its `$q`.

I wrote a service as follows:

```
Get.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];
function Get($q, $http) {
    return {
        get: function(url) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get(url + '?' + Math.random()).success(function(data) {
                alert('Got data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}
```

and used it like

```
$q.all(Get.get('backend/index.php/poster/pull'), Get.get('data/poster_past.json')).then(
                function(NewAndOldPosters) {
                    alert("Old and New: " + JSON.stringify(NewAndOldPosters));
                }
    );
```

But I received an alert as `"Old and New: {"$$state":{"status":0}}"` before I received the alert of the actual data `"Got Data: ......"`. How can this happen that `$q.all` does not work as expected?

Comment: Try wrapping your promises in an array - `[Get.get('backend/index.php/poster/pull'), Get.get('data/poster_past.json')]`

Comment: the argument for $q.all is either an array or object of promises.

Comment: Don't use the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your promises in an array:

```
[Get.get('backend/index.php/poster/pull'),Get.get('data/poster_past.json')]
```